# Radeon HD6870 fan goes frenzy after unsuspend

Tags: drivers, radeon, fan, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 14.04:

```
Linux hometower 3.16.0-71-generic #91~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 19:43:36 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have Radeon HD6870 Video Card, which is working properly and very quiet.
Unfortunately when I suspend the PC and unsuspend it afterwards - the fan goes crazy and very noisy.

I am using the "**driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)**".

I should point that I was playing CS: GO on the same configuration with Windows 10 flawlessly, but now the FPS even with lower graphics settings is a bit lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix it with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo aticonfig --pplib-cmd "set fanspeed 0 20"
```